# Not sure why my code isn't adding and printing my linked list?

Tags: c, list, syntax

Here's my linked list it contains a string version of keys which holds a string representation of contents:

```
struct node{
    char key[10];
    char content;
struct node *next;
};
struct node *head=(struct node *) NULL;
struct node *tail=(struct node *) NULL;

struct node * initinode(char *key, char content)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = (struct node *) calloc( 1, sizeof(struct node ) );
    if( ptr == NULL )                       
        return (struct node *) NULL;        
    else {                                  
        strcpy( ptr->key, key );          
        ptr->content = content;                       
        return ptr;                         
    }
}
void printnode( struct node *ptr )
{
    printf("Key ->%s\n", ptr->key );
    printf("Contents   ->%d\n", ptr->content );
}
void printlist( struct node *ptr )
{
    while( ptr != NULL )        
    {
        printnode( ptr );        
        ptr = ptr->next;         
    }
}
void add( struct node *new )  
{
    if( head == NULL )      
        head = new;         
    tail->next = new;       
    tail->next = NULL;      
    tail= new;              
}

struct node * searchname( struct node *ptr, char *key )
{
    while( strcmp( key, ptr->key ) != 0 ) {    
        ptr = ptr->next;                         
        if( ptr == NULL )                        
            break;                                
    }
    return ptr;                                 
}                     

//-----------------------------add to the list number of files and print list

int file_count = 0;
DIR * dirp;
struct dirent * entry;
dirp = opendir(cwd); 
while ((entry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
{
    if (entry->d_type == DT_REG) { /* If the entry is a regular file */
        file_count++;
    }
}
printf("%d \n",file_count);
char file=(char)file_count;
closedir(dirp);

ptr=initinode(files, file);
add(ptr);
printlist( head );
//-----------------------------------casting
```

In addtion to that question I want to add different datatypes to my list in its string represented form. I want to try casting it to a string but it seems the method I used for this would not work on others. And if you suggest diving a void dataype for the list please explain thoroughly.

Thank you

Comment: Please fix the formatting on this post. It's impossible to read.

Comment: ok fixed sorry about that im new to this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I have a comment here

```
void add( struct node *new )  
{
    if( head == NULL )      
        head = new;         
    tail->next = new;        // Making tail point to next node
    tail->next = NULL;      // but, immediately setting tail to NULL --> problem
    tail= new;              // tail pointing to new but connection to previous node lost
}
```

I feel that the function could be

```
void add( struct node *new )  
{
    if( head == NULL ) {      
        head = new;
        tail = new; // Grow at tail and keep head static
    }
    else {         
        tail->next = new;        // Connect current node to next
        tail= new;              // Move tail to new node
        tail->next = NULL;      // Since this is the last node, set next to NULL
    }
}
```

There is another point to be considered. In this call, `printlist( head );` you are passing the `head` pointer which is getting updated inside the function.  I feel it may be a good idea to make a copy of `head` and pass the same to the function, so that `head` always points to first element of the list.

P.S: Please avoid naming a variable as `new` as it is a keyword in `C++`

Comment: I will keep the new keyword in mind. sorry about that I have never learned c++. A problem still exists within my code since it still builds correctly it just doesn't run correctly.

Comment: @Noobprogrammer I have just updated the comment with another small point. Can you please elaborate when you say that the code doesn't run correctly?

Comment: The code will compile but when it comes to run time it will just fail and not print anything and since it compiled its hard to pin point the error.

Comment: maybe I forgot to save before but now my list is working thank you so much for your help